# Remove text from filenames and create separate archives

Tags: batch-file, rename, archive

I have directory containing a lot of files as the example:

> The Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde - Robert Louis Stevenson.doc
>   The Trial - Franz Kafka.doc
>   Les Miserables - Victor Hugo.prc
>   Women In Love - D. H. Lawrence.mobi
>   Kidnapped - Robert Louis Stevenson.prc
>   Room - Emma Donoghue.pdf

Please help me to write a CMD command to rename all files and output like that:

> The Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde.doc
>   The Trial.doc
>   Les Miserables.prc
>   Women In Love. H. Lawrence.mobi
>   Kidnapped.prc
>   Room.pdf

and then archive files separately:

> The Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde.rar
>   The Trial.rar
>   Les Miserables.rar
>   Women In Love.rar
>   Kidnapped.rar
>   Room.rar

P/s: I have written a command to archive files but it didn't work. Where is it wrong?

> for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir "*.*" /ad /b') do (
>   "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -r -tzip "%%b.zip"
>   )

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=U:\books"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

CALL :makedummydata

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" ') DO (
 FOR /f "delims=-" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
  SET "book=%%b"
  ECHO export? ren? "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!book:~0,-1!%%~xa"
  ECHO "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -r -tzip "%destdir%\!book:~0,-1!.zip" "%sourcedir%\!book:~0,-1!%%~xa"
  ECHO "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -r -tzip "%destdir%\!book:~0,-1!.zip" "%sourcedir%\%%a"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

:makedummydata

::
:: This part is just to set up the files as specified on my test directory u:\books
::
MD "%sourcedir%" 2>nul
FOR %%b IN (
"The Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde - Robert Louis Stevenson.doc"
"The Trial - Franz Kafka.doc"
"Les Miserables - Victor Hugo.prc"
"Women In Love - D. H. Lawrence.mobi"
"Kidnapped - Robert Louis Stevenson.prc"
"Pride & Prejudice - Jane Austen.prc"
"Room - Emma Donoghue.pdf"
 ) DO (
  COPY /y NUL "%sourcedir%\%%~b" >nul
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Not sure what you mean by `export`. Rename, perhaps?

I've shown how to execute the `7z` command, but I've no idea whether you want to rename the file first or do it in a single step. I've assumed that each book is titled as `name - author.ext` with a space each side of the `-`.

The commands are simply `echo`ed so you can verify before executing.

Note that this won't work properly if there are certain characters in the title - especially `"`, although `&` seems happy - that's why I made an addition.

Another thing to worry about is the use of `-` as a separator. What happens with a title that contains `-` - or if the author's name contains a `-` - or both?

---

Oh no! The dread "It doesn't work" response with no detail of what the procedure did or didn't do.

Here's a revised batch incorporating the extra detail provided. ** with the caution that it creates a set of dummy files in dummy directories, then renames and archives them. **

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=U:\books"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

CALL :makedummydata

ECHO before...
DIR %sourcedir%
DIR %destdir%

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" ') DO (
 FOR /f "delims=-" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
  SET "book=%%b"
  ren "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!book:~0,-1!%%~xa"
  "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -r -tzip "%destdir%\!book:~0,-1!.zip" "%sourcedir%\!book:~0,-1!%%~xa"
 )
)
ECHO after...
DIR %sourcedir%
DIR %destdir%

GOTO :EOF

:makedummydata

::
:: This part is just to set up the files as specified on my test directory u:\books
::
MD "%sourcedir%" 2>nul
MD "%destdir%" 2>nul
REM DEL "%sourcedir%\*?*" 2>nul
REM del "%destdir%\*?*" 2>nul
FOR %%b IN (
"The Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde - Robert Louis Stevenson.doc"
"The Trial - Franz Kafka.doc"
"Les Miserables - Victor Hugo.prc"
"Women In Love - D. H. Lawrence.mobi"
"Kidnapped - Robert Louis Stevenson.prc"
"Pride & Prejudice - Jane Austen.prc"
"Room - Emma Donoghue.pdf"
 ) DO (
  COPY /y NUL "%sourcedir%\%%~b" >nul
)
GOTO :EOF
```

And here's the result I got on running:

```
before...
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 02E6-1000

 Directory of U:\books

28/03/2014  11:40    <DIR>          .
28/03/2014  11:40    <DIR>          ..
28/03/2014  11:46                 0 The Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde - Robert Louis Stevenson.doc
28/03/2014  11:46                 0 The Trial - Franz Kafka.doc
28/03/2014  11:46                 0 Les Miserables - Victor Hugo.prc
28/03/2014  11:46                 0 Women In Love - D. H. Lawrence.mobi
28/03/2014  11:46                 0 Kidnapped - Robert Louis Stevenson.prc
28/03/2014  11:46                 0 Pride & Prejudice - Jane Austen.prc
28/03/2014  11:46                 0 Room - Emma Donoghue.pdf
               7 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,145,681,408 bytes free
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 02E6-1000

 Directory of U:\destdir

28/03/2014  11:40    <DIR>          .
28/03/2014  11:40    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,145,681,408 bytes free

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive U:\destdir\The Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde.zip

Compressing  The Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde.doc

Everything is Ok

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive U:\destdir\The Trial.zip

Compressing  The Trial.doc

Everything is Ok

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive U:\destdir\Les Miserables.zip

Compressing  Les Miserables.prc

Everything is Ok

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive U:\destdir\Women In Love.zip

Compressing  Women In Love.mobi

Everything is Ok

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive U:\destdir\Kidnapped.zip

Compressing  Kidnapped.prc

Everything is Ok

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive U:\destdir\Pride & Prejudice.zip

Compressing  Pride & Prejudice.prc

Everything is Ok

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive U:\destdir\Room.zip

Compressing  Room.pdf

Everything is Ok
after...
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 02E6-1000

 Directory of U:\books

28/03/2014  11:40    <DIR>          .
28/03/2014  11:40    <DIR>          ..
28/03/2014  11:46                 0 The Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde.doc
28/03/2014  11:46                 0 The Trial.doc
28/03/2014  11:46                 0 Les Miserables.prc
28/03/2014  11:46                 0 Women In Love.mobi
28/03/2014  11:46                 0 Kidnapped.prc
28/03/2014  11:46                 0 Pride & Prejudice.prc
28/03/2014  11:46                 0 Room.pdf
               7 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,145,452,032 bytes free
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 02E6-1000

 Directory of U:\destdir

28/03/2014  11:40    <DIR>          .
28/03/2014  11:40    <DIR>          ..
28/03/2014  11:46               224 The Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde.zip
28/03/2014  11:46               160 The Trial.zip
28/03/2014  11:46               170 Les Miserables.zip
28/03/2014  11:46               170 Women In Love.zip
28/03/2014  11:46               160 Kidnapped.zip
28/03/2014  11:46               176 Pride & Prejudice.zip
28/03/2014  11:46               150 Room.zip
               7 File(s)          1,210 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,145,452,032 bytes free
```

**Note that the required REN and 7Z commands have now been activated**

**Note also that there are two `DEL` commands REMmed-out** These would clear the two dummy directories, but I'm uncomfortable about publishing code that destroys anything - just in case of a typo. **Only delete the `REM` keyword if you've checked that the `DEL` commands are correct**

Comment: I had tried your new batch and change "FOR %%b IN (...)" to "FOR %%b IN (*.doc *.prc *.pdf)". 2 new folders are created called "books" and "destdir". However, just some of files are renamed in "books" and there are no archive files. (If not change, the rename is fine but the archive doesn't work) (the photo: http://goo.gl/0adgiR )

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using regular expressions to parse the filenames and it will only fail if there is a `" - "` in the title part of the name and it would chop the name off there.  Foreign characters and Unicode can be an issue too.

The script is in the last 6 lines - the lines above it just create some dummy files to test this with - so launch it in an empty folder to test it.

The `del` command deletes the original files after archiving.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (
"The Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde - Robert Louis Stevenson.doc"
"The Trial - Franz Kafka.doc"
"Les Miserables - Victor Hugo.prc"
"Women In Love - D. H. Lawrence.mobi"
"Kidnapped - Robert Louis Stevenson.prc"
"Room - Emma Donoghue.pdf"
) do type nul>"%%a"

:: remove the above after testing


for /f "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d ^|find /v /i "%~nx0" ^|find /v /i "repl.bat" ^|repl "(.*?) - .*(\..*)$" "$&|$1$2" a') do (
ren "%%a" "%%b"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~nb" "%%b"
del "%%b"
)
pause
```

Comment: I puts all them in the same folder, after run the batch, everything disappears. O_O (batch or files are gone)

Comment: It deletes the files that were created (and then renamed) but it leaves the archives and batch files alone.  Do you have `7z.exe` in that location?  What error messages do you see on the screen?  try copy and pasting it again.  Did you download repl.bat ?

Comment: It's again. I put 7z.exe, repl.bat and rename.bat(with the above content) in a folder. Everything is gone.   http://tinyurl.com/mxpjqhf    . With No, nothing happens. With Yes, all is gone.

Comment: Point 1) don't put 7z.exe in there - Adjust the path to the 7z.exe file if it is wrong.  Put the batch file and repl.bat in an empty folder and run the batch file.  Don't call it `RENAME.BAT` because rename is a system command - try calling it `renamefiles.bat` and then you should see a bunch of archives with a file inside - that is zero bytes in size.  If that works, then remove the lines at the top but leave `@echo off` there - and put some `copies` of your files there and try it.

Comment: I also changed one character in the batch file from x to a in the repl command.  That will stop it trying to process any file that doesn't have `" - "` in it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but it seem like an impossible mission.  I give up. Thanks so much.